# how to find all records from postgresql database using spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am new to postgresql database and using hibernate+ spring.I want to know how to write query for retrieve all rows from a table.I don't know how to write query in DAOIMPL. I completed create-service successfully.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT_RECORD")
public class StudentRecord{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;


@Column(name = "student_Name")
private String studentName; 

@Column(name = "student_Id")
private String studentId; 

''''
getter setter methods..
....
....
}

studentDaoImpl:

@Repository
@Transactional
public class studentDaoImpl implements studentDao{
@Override
public List<StudentRecord> studentRecord() {
    List<StudentRecord> entities = null;
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("SELECT e.* STUDENT_RECORD e");
    entities = sql.list();
    return entities;

}
 }
```

my studentName table have 5 records and also completed controller for Get method. Please help me.

Comment: Please, add your code with a query (your try).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you've got your entity mapped.

Next thing to do is to write a service to retrieve it.

Assuming you've got spring correctly configured using annotations.

Define StudentRecordRepository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRecordRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentRecord, Long>  {

}
```

**Note!** Your repository extends `JpaRepository`. There are some basic methods defined in the `JpaRepository` that allows you to do basic CRUD operations on `StudentRecord` entity.

In you controller class you inject the repository like this:

```
@Controller 
public class StudentRecordController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRecordRepository studentRecordRepository;


}
```

After you injected repository into your controller, you can find all StudentRecords like this:

```
studentRecordRepository.findAll();
```